# I'm having problem to connect auth0 authorization from a create-react-app project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, auth0, react-router-dom

I'm setting up a create-react project and currently working on the authentication part to log in into the user profile using auth0. I ran the code independently (downloaded from the auth0 website) and it worked however when I combined it with my existing project, it didn't seem to render properly.

I have 4 main js files that are index.js, main.js , Home.js(Component) and routes.js to render the home page.

package.json file (dependencies only)

```
"dependencies": {
"@material-ui/core": "^4.0.2",
"auth0-js": "^9.10.4",
"bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
"clsx": "1.0.4",
"react": "16.8.6",
"react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.9",
"react-dom": "16.8.6",
"react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
"react-scripts": "2.1.8"
   },
```

index.js file

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import { createMuiTheme, MuiThemeProvider } from "@material- 
ui/core/styles";
import deepOrange from "@material-ui/core/colors/deepOrange";

//for auth0
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import { makeMainRoutes } from "./routes";
import { Navbar, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import Home from "./components/Home";

//react-router-dom
import "./styles.css";


class App extends Component {
  goTo(route) {
    this.props.history.replace(`/${route}`);
  }

  login() {
    this.props.auth.login();
  }

  logout() {
    this.props.auth.logout();
  }

   componentDidMount() {
     const { renewSession } = this.props.auth;

     if (localStorage.getItem("isLoggedIn") === "true") {
       renewSession();
     }
   }

   render() {
     const { isAuthenticated } = this.props.auth;
     return (
       <div>
         <MuiThemeProvider
          theme={createMuiTheme({
           palette: {
          primary: deepOrange,
          secondary: deepOrange
           }
         })}
       />
       <Home />
       <Navbar fluid>
         <Navbar.Header>
           <Navbar.Brand>
            <a href="#">Auth0 - React</a>
          </Navbar.Brand>
        <Button
          bsStyle="primary"
          className="btn-margin"
          onClick={this.goTo.bind(this, "home")}
        >
          Home
        </Button>
        {!isAuthenticated() && (
          <Button
            id="qsLoginBtn"
            bsStyle="primary"
            className="btn-margin"
            onClick={this.login.bind(this)}
          >
            Log In
          </Button>
        )}
        {isAuthenticated() && (
          <Button
            id="qsLogoutBtn"
            bsStyle="primary"
            className="btn-margin"
            onClick={this.logout.bind(this)}
          >
            Log Out
          </Button>
        )}
      </Navbar.Header>
        </Navbar>
       </div>
        );
       }
     }

    export default App;

   const routes = makeMainRoutes();
   ReactDOM.render(routes, document.getElementById("root"));
```

main.js

```
  import React, { useState } from "react";
  import { createMuiTheme, MuiThemeProvider } from "@material- 
  ui/core/styles";
  import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
  import Icon from "@material-ui/core/Icon";

  import deepOrange from "@material-ui/core/colors/deepOrange";

  import { Root, Header, Nav, Content, Footer, presets } from 
   "./Layout";
  import NavContentEx from "./components/NavContentEx";
  import NavHeaderEx from "./components/NavHeaderEx";
  import HeaderEx from "./components/HeaderEx";
  import ContentEx from "./components/ContentEx";
  import FooterEx from "./components/FooterEx";
  import MediaCard from "./components/Card";

   function Main() {
   const [loading] = useState(false);
   const [preset] = useState("createDefaultLayout");
   const [data] = useState({
    header: true,
     nav: true,
     content: true,
     footer: true
    });
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider
       theme={createMuiTheme({
        palette: {
          primary: deepOrange,
          secondary: deepOrange
         }
       })}
     >
     {loading ? (
    <div
      style={{
        height: "100vh",
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center"
         }}
        />
      ) : (
    <Root config={presets[preset]()} style={{ minHeight: "100vh" }}>
      <CssBaseline />

      <Header
        menuIcon={{
          inactive: <Icon>menu_rounded</Icon>,
          active: <Icon>chevron_left</Icon>
        }}
      >
        {({ screen, collapsed }) =>
          data.header && <HeaderEx screen={screen} collapsed= 
       {collapsed} />
        }
      </Header>

      <Nav
        collapsedIcon={{
          inactive: <Icon>chevron_left</Icon>,
          active: <Icon>chevron_right</Icon>
        }}
        header={({ collapsed }) =>
          data.nav && <NavHeaderEx collapsed={collapsed} />
        }
      >
        {data.nav && <NavContentEx />}
      </Nav>
      <Content>
        <div>
          <MediaCard />
        </div>

        {data.content && <ContentEx />}
      </Content>

      <Footer>{data.footer && <FooterEx />}</Footer>
    </Root>
       )}
    </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
    }

    export default Main;
```

routes.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, BrowserRouter, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./index";
import Main from "./main";
import Callback from "./Callback/Callback";
import Auth from "./Auth/Auth";
import history from "./history";

 const auth = new Auth();

  const handleAuthentication = ({ location }) => {
   if (/access_token|id_token|error/.test(location.hash)) {
     auth.handleAuthentication();
   }
  };

  export const makeMainRoutes = () => {
    return (
     <BrowserRouter history={history}>
       <Switch>
     <Route path="/" render={props => <App auth={auth} {...props} 
      />} />
    <Route path="/main" render={props => <Main auth={auth} 
      {...props} />} />
    <Route
      path="/callback"
      render={props => {
        handleAuthentication(props);
        return <Callback {...props} />;
      }}
    />
     </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
   };
```

Home.js

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Home extends Component {
  login() {
this.props.auth.login();
  }
    render() {
  const { isAuthenticated } = this.props.auth;
    return (
     <div className="container">
     {
      isAuthenticated() && (
          <h4>
            You are logged in!
          </h4>
        )
      }
       {
      !isAuthenticated() && (
          <h4>
            You are not logged in! Please{' '}
            <a style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}
              onClick={this.login.bind(this)}>
              Log In
            </a>
            {' '}to continue.
          </h4>
        )
       }
     </div>
   );
   }
  }

  export default Home;
```

EDIT* Auth.js file added

```
 import history from "../history";
 import auth0 from "auth0-js";
 import { AUTH_CONFIG } from "./auth0-variables";

  export default class Auth {
  accessToken;
  idToken;
  expiresAt;

  auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({
   domain: AUTH_CONFIG.domain,
   clientID: AUTH_CONFIG.clientID,
   redirectUri: AUTH_CONFIG.callbackUrl,
    responseType: "token id_token",
    scope: "openid"
   });

   constructor() {
    this.login = this.login.bind(this);
    this.logout = this.logout.bind(this);
    this.handleAuthentication = this.handleAuthentication.bind(this);
    this.isAuthenticated = this.isAuthenticated.bind(this);
    this.getAccessToken = this.getAccessToken.bind(this);
    this.getIdToken = this.getIdToken.bind(this);
    this.renewSession = this.renewSession.bind(this);
     }

   login() {
   this.auth0.authorize();
   }   

   handleAuthentication() {
   this.auth0.parseHash((err, authResult) => {
  if (authResult && authResult.accessToken && authResult.idToken) {
    this.setSession(authResult);
  } else if (err) {
    history.replace("/main");
    console.log(err);
    alert(`Error: ${err.error}. Check the console for further 
   details.`);
      }
   });
  }

   getAccessToken() {
    return this.accessToken;
   }

  getIdToken() {
   return this.idToken;
  }

 setSession(authResult) {
// Set isLoggedIn flag in localStorage
localStorage.setItem("isLoggedIn", "true");

// Set the time that the access token will expire at
let expiresAt = authResult.expiresIn * 1000 + new Date().getTime();
this.accessToken = authResult.accessToken;
this.idToken = authResult.idToken;
this.expiresAt = expiresAt;

// navigate to the home route
history.replace("/main");
  }

  renewSession() {
    this.auth0.checkSession({}, (err, authResult) => {
     if (authResult && authResult.accessToken && authResult.idToken) {
       this.setSession(authResult);
     } else if (err) {
    this.logout();
    console.log(err);
    alert(
      `Could not get a new token (${err.error}: 
    ${err.error_description}).`
      );
    }
  });
 }

  logout() {
// Remove tokens and expiry time
this.accessToken = null;
this.idToken = null;
this.expiresAt = 0;

// Remove isLoggedIn flag from localStorage
localStorage.removeItem("isLoggedIn");

this.auth0.logout({
  returnTo: window.location.origin
});

// navigate to the home route
history.replace("/main");
  }

  isAuthenticated() {
// Check whether the current time is past the
// access token's expiry time
let expiresAt = this.expiresAt;
return new Date().getTime() < expiresAt;
 }
 }
```

Some of the errors are as below;

1. Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `App`."

2. TypeError: Cannot read property 'isAuthenticated' of undefined

Comment: You are using auth object in Home component but I see Home component is called without any props ? How does Home component gets auth object

Comment: I have included the Auth.js code above where the Home component gets the auth object

Comment: Your index.js file (App class) calls <Home /> component without any props and I don't see home is exported with any wrapper. Try <Home auth={this.props.auth} /> in App class render.

Comment: The error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'isAuthenticated' of undefined" is already gone but the first error still persists.

Comment: replace last two lines in index.js with these:
   const Routes = makeMainRoutes();
   ReactDOM.render(<Routes />, document.getElementById("root"));

Comment: Doesn't seemed to work but the first error is gone. Now, there is a new error though. "Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.